# PHP - strpos() with whitespace

Tags: php, regex, pcre, strpos

`imap subject = "code. 115 is your id"`

I tried using below one but didnt worked.

```
$headerInfo = imap_headerinfo($connection);
if (!strpos($headerInfo->subject, "code. $id")) {
    echo true 
}

$headerInfo = imap_headerinfo($connection);
if (!strpos($headerInfo->subject, "code.$id")) {
    echo true 
}
```

How can I fetch that?

Answer (score 1):

You could extract the `$id` using a regular expression `capture group`.

```
<?php
$id = getId('imap subject = "code. 115 is your id"'); // is 115
$id = getId('imap subject = "code.115.00 is your id"'); // is 115

function getId($subject) {
    $r = [];
    if (preg_match("/code\. ?([0-9]+)(\.00)? is your id/", $subject, $r)) {
        return $r[1];
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("Couldn't match subject");
    }
}
```

Now you only need to check if this `$id` is your id :)

```
$id = getId($headerInfo->subject);
if ($id == '119')
```

Comment: @kinger123 And what exactly would you like to do with that data? Extract `115.00` to a variable? Check if it is contained in a variable?

Comment: Yes. Exactly! Checks if it is contained in a variable. but Only sometimes i receive in decimals.

Comment: Ok, let me clear this up. Sometimes you have `imap subject = "code. 249 is your id"` and sometimes `imap subject = "code. 249.00 is your id"`, where `249` is in your `$id` variable, is that correct?

Comment: Yes. But the thing is When there is a space then there will not any decimals. When there is no space there will be decimals. But 95% of times i receive the subject as `Code. $id is your id` only

Comment: There i a lot more in the subject  `Code. $id is your id. Date: xx  Time: xx` Should i add Literally?

Comment: You only have to add so much to distinguish your id `115` from other numbers. For example, if you string looks like this `I'm 19 years old and have 192cm`, then the pattern `/[0-9]+/` would match both `19` and `192` as your age. So we surround it with `/I'm [0-9]+ years/` to make it clear, that we want **that** number, not the other. I could also add `/I'm [0-9]+ years old and have /` to make it even more clear, but that's not necessary in this case.

Comment: To summarize: If the part `code. $id is your id` appears only **once** in your whole string, then no: you don't have to add more string literals :) If this solves your problem, consider accepting this answer.

Comment: my problem will be solved easily if i can limit the imap subject fetch. Like Upto Fetching first two words. So the $id will be exact.

Comment: You would need to know exactly how long the `$id` should be. For 3 digit number, it's ok, but what if the id is 2 digit, 4 digit or more-digit integer?

Comment: 100% Sure not more than 4Digit Number.

Comment: Suit yourself :)

Comment: Hey! Thanks. Preg_match Your first Code is working. But the execution time is little slow when compared to strpos.

Answer (score 1):

`strpos` will return 0, because `code` is at the start of the string. 0 evaluates to false when using a loose comparison such as `!`. What you need to do is make sure it doesn't have a strict evaluation to false:

```
if (strpos($headerInfo->subject, "code. $id") !== FALSE) {
    echo true;
}
```

Comment: This is also fetching the other integers present in the subject. Not only the integers that came after `Code. 11 is your id. time : 13:10`